# pg_logical replication failing - Postgresql 11.9

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication, pglogical

Need some help with pglogical replication. Following is my replication setup:

On the Publisher side, node created successfully.
I applied row filtering on a column for some tables. Something like:

```
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(set_name:= 'default', relation := 'table_1', row_filter:= ' country=''USA'' ');

SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(set_name:= 'default', relation := 'table_2', row_filter:= ' country=''USA'' ');

SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(set_name:= 'default', relation := 'table_3', row_filter:= ' country=''USA'' ');
```

On the Subscriber side, node created successfully. When I create the subscription to the publisher, the `pglogical.show_subscription_status()` stays in `initializing` status for sometime and then changes to `down`
I checked the subscriber DB logs and I see the following error:

```
LOG:  statement: COPY "public"."table_1"("id","column_1","column_2",...........,"some_column") FROM stdin
ERROR:  null value in column "some_column" violates not-null constraint
```

I check the Publisher and there are no NULL values in `some_column` in `table_1`. I also checked the specific row in `table_1` which error'ed out and the `some_column's` value is 'f'. The `some_column` is a `Boolean NOT NULL` column.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this bug: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/issues/8 what is the version of pglogical you are using ?

Comment: @mshabou -- I am using pglogical on an Aurora instance with Postgres 11.9 ..... How to check with pglogical version is installed?